# excel vba find the column with certain value and copy below values

Tags: excel, vba

I still couldn't figure out how I can do the below despite numerous attempts.

I am trying to

1. Search for a certain text/value in a range of headers of various
   worksheets (the certain text/value from a different worksheet "DB")
2. When a header with that value is found, copy all the data below that header and paste it as a value in that same column
3. Copy the formula that is 1 column to the right of column with matched header and copy that cell to the last row of a defined column
   column of that corresponding worksheet
   (e.g., if header with the
   value is found on H11, copy the formula of I12 and paste upto last
   row of A in column I)
4. Repeat this for all headers in the range of various worksheets

I have the following and although I can achieve #1, I seemed to have trouble selecting the right cell. Any help will be appreciated!

```
Dim period As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

period = Worksheets("DB").Range("A1")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case ws.Name
    Case "Total", "PH4", "Product"
        With ws
            For Each rng In .Range("G11:Z11")
                If rng.Value = period Then

                    'Change the data below the header into values
                    Range(rng.Column & "12:" & rng.Column & .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Value = Value

                    'copy formula on the right
                    Range(rng.Column + 1 & "12").Copy
                    Range(rng.Column + 1 & "12:" & rng.Column + 1 & .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

                    Exit For
                End If
            Next rng
        End With
    End Select
Next ws
```

Comment: instead of `Range(rng.Column & "12:" & rng.Column & .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Value = Value` you can do `.Columns(rng.Column).Value = .Columns(rng.Column).Value`

Comment: Also your `range` is not qualified. It will refer to the activesheet unless you put a DOT before it.. For example `.Range(...`

Comment: what I need some of the cells in that column to stay as formula? 
your suggestion changes every cell in that column to value